# Some people are not determined to win

Tags: meaning

Does it mean

1. He doesn't have a strong will to win
2. Gods do not decide that he should win

Bonus: How those 2 meaning of determined related? One means strong will, another means predestination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost certainly means the first. To have the second meaning unambiguously it would have to be something like *Some people are predestined not to win*. But, as I have to keep saying, it all depends on the context.